# Diagnosing slow WAN to LAN throughput on home router (wired, not wifi)

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, dd-wrt

## The hardware

- Cable Modem: Arris Surfboard 6121
- Router:      TP-Link Archer C5 v1.2

  - I switched to DD-WRT firmware after observing the problem on stock firmware
  - Apparently, the C5 v1.2 has identical hardware to the C7 v2

## The mystery

My modem is fast.

- My laptop connected directly to the modem gets speeds ~75 Mbps. This is **great**!

The router is also fast.

- I used `iperf3` to measure wired connections between two computers when wired, when on wifi, and between the router and a computer. All of these are fast.

However, when I plug the router into the modem, I cannot get faster than 18 Mbps.  I am measuring over a wired connection.

### What I've tried (with no success)

- Buying new patch cables
- Replacing stock firmware with DD-WRT
- Switching from hardware NAT to software NAT
- Putting my test machine on the DMZ to eliminate slow NAT
- Switching function of LAN and WAN ports
- Asking my ISP to reprovision the modem

---

Any ideas?

Comment: "All of these are fast." - and yet none of these involve routing. :D Though 18 Mbps certainly doesn't sound right. There is no DMZ by the way, the correct term is "Exposed Host" and it's still subject to NAT.

Comment: I recognize that none of those involve routing -- I was just trying to highlight that it's not a 10 Mbit port.  I suppose you're right that my DMZ host is still subject to NAT, since its IP is on my local subnet.

Comment: Do you know if DD-WRT allows me to expose a host?  I'm not sure how to test whether NAT is slowing me down.

Comment: You can always put a computer on the WAN side and test actual routing/NAT performance that way. Exposing a host is what you're doing already. With a single public IP address you can't do anything else either.

Comment: That is a good idea, though it's the most annoying test to do :) I guess I would set static IPs and manually add routes to each computer and then run iperf3 or something similar.

Comment: You’d set a static IP on both the router’s WAN interface and the “WAN PC”. The rest can stay as is, no need for static routes or anything.

Comment: Have you tried a ping test on your router, on some device like a smart TV on your home, and on some known location on the internet?  The difference in delay times can help tell you where the trouble is.  Also, there are some pretty good speed tests available for download.  I hesitate to recomend one, because I'm too ignorant, and your situation may be different from mine.

Comment: Does the modem contain a router?  If so, is it configured in bridge mode?  When two routers are struggling with each other, they hardly have time for anything else.